# Discord.py: list index out of range when assigning elements to variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a command inside a cog to solve a quadratic equation.
The user must send the command followed by three numbers separated with spaces, my function looks like this:

```py
async def general(self, ctx, nums):
    try:
        num = map(int, nums.split())
        new_list = list(num)
        for num in new_list:
            if num < 0:
                raise ValueError

        a = new_list[0]
        b = new_list[1]
        c = new_list[2]

        root = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c)
        x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(root)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(root)) / (2 * a)

        await ctx.send(f"X1: {x1}\nX2: {x2}")

    except ValueError:
        await ctx.send("Error message")
```

If I send the command `.general 1 1 -2` I get the next error:

```
b = new_list[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When adding a `print(new_list)` seems like the function is only saving the index [0], also I tried with deleting the `for` but it keeps on giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that you forgot to add a * inside your function parameters. Since there isn't a *, your function is only seeing the first argument after the command name (in your case, it sees '.general 1'). Changing it to this should fix it. You can read about this in the [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments).

```py
async def general(self, ctx, *, nums):
    try:
        num = map(int, nums.split())
        new_list = list(num)
        for num in new_list:
            if num < 0:
                raise ValueError

        a = new_list[0]
        b = new_list[1]
        c = new_list[2]

        root = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c)
        x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(root)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(root)) / (2 * a)

        await ctx.send(f"X1: {x1}\nX2: {x2}")

    except ValueError:
        await ctx.send("Error message")
```